# How to install PHP .rar package?

Tags: php, installation, package, rar

I'm new in installing packages on server. On php.net it says how you can install rar package by hand (http://www.php.net/manual/en/rar.installation.php):

```
gunzip rar-xxx.tgz
tar -xvf rar-xxx.tar
cd rar-xxx
phpize
./configure && make && make install
```

I've downloaded the package and uploaded it to server. My question is, **WHERE** do I need to write the installation commands? I've tried in CMD but, of course, it doesn't work. Help? :)

Comment: Are you using linux or windows? These are linux instructions.

Comment: Do you even have root access to install the package on your server? Or do you have a webhosting package? If so you can't do this. You have to contact your provider.

Comment: it is linux,
i have root access

Comment: What part of it fails? What's the error? The last line needs to be run as root/sudo

Comment: the problem is I don't know where, in what program, do you copy-paste these command lines?

Comment: @Augustus what kind of hosting package do you have, a VPS or dedicated server?

Comment: It is not _.rar package_, it's _Rar package_. _.rar_ is a Winrar compressed file type extention!

Comment: Ok, I've maybe mislead you on this question. I have a simple Shared hosting, and as Tobias pointed earlier, thats why I don't have access to the terminal to install Rar package, that is avaliable only through VPS or dedicated? 
Did I understand it correctly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need SSH access to the Linux machine you want to install this on. By the sound of your comments you either don't have SSH access (shared hosts) or don't know how to use it.

If you have SSH access to the server you're working on use a program like [PuTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/) to establish an SSH connection to the server. Once you've logged in with your SSH credentials type these commands:

```
cd /tmp
wget http://pecl.php.net/get/rar-3.0.1.tgz
gunzip rar-3.0.1.tgz
tar -xvf rar-3.0.1.tar
cd rar-3.0.1
phpize
./configure && make && make install
```

Comment: I get an error saying shtool at '/tmp/rar-3.0.1/build/shtool' does not exist or is not executable